# How to understand the the inspired metanarrative of the Judges periodic to late Monarchic Scriptures?

Tags: inspiration

As a Christian I can see the early OT involving God's guidance through sacred etiological myths, setting apart from ANE, and origins.

I understand that the time of the judges to post-Davidic kingdoms had their purpose, but I struggle with them.

Much of that period reads like propaganda and has continual senseless violence. I can understand the exilic/post-exilic redactor authors (if one subscribes to this) establishing the primacy of Judah, the temple, and David as part of religious/national identity.

In terms of inspiration, it is hard to justify. All of David's potential competitors die conveniently without blame on David. It all reads like what would one expect of Bronze age warring states with a commentary on whether the rulers followed God and thus were blessed or did not and were cursed.